# Pandas dataframe with multiple frequency data

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe data with three frequencies (in some data there are even more)

```
    Date        value frequency  
23/10/2016 20:31    0    00:06
23/10/2016 20:36    0.5  00:05
23/10/2016 20:43    0.2  00:07
23/10/2016 20:49    0.1  00:06
23/10/2016 20:54    0    00:05
23/10/2016 21:00    2    00:06
23/10/2016 21:06    4    00:06
23/10/2016 21:12    5    00:06
23/10/2016 21:18    6    00:06
23/10/2016 21:24    10   00:06
23/10/2016 21:31    0    00:07
23/10/2016 21:37    0    00:06
23/10/2016 21:43    0    00:06
23/10/2016 21:48    7    00:05
23/10/2016 21:55    10   00:07
23/10/2016 22:00    0    00:05
23/10/2016 22:06    0    00:06
23/10/2016 22:12    0    00:06
23/10/2016 22:18    0    00:06
23/10/2016 22:25    0    00:07
23/10/2016 22:31    0    00:06
```

What I want of this data is I want to re sample to 15 mins, is there a way that panda handle multiple frequency data while creating index and that can be used for re-sampling the data.

I tried like this :

```
df=my_data_frame
df.index=df['Date']
df.resample('15T').sum()
```

This is giving me weird result like this :

```
Date                value
10/01/2016 22:15    0
10/01/2016 22:30    0
10/01/2016 22:45    0
10/01/2016 23:00    0
10/01/2016 23:15    0
10/01/2016 23:30    0
10/01/2016 23:45    0
11/01/2016 0:00 
11/01/2016 0:15 
11/01/2016 0:30 
11/01/2016 0:45 
11/01/2016 1:00 
11/01/2016 1:15 
11/01/2016 1:30 
11/01/2016 1:45 
11/01/2016 2:00 
11/01/2016 2:15 
11/01/2016 2:30 
11/01/2016 2:45 
11/01/2016 3:00
```

Index has been changed... ?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: it gave weird result how ? what's your expected result ?

Comment: @Allen, I want 15 min re-sample data. I have also shown the result what I got after I re sample. I have a feeling that there might be a problem while setting index.

Comment: Can you add the output of `df.head().to_dict()`  here?

Comment: @ayhan, here is goes

 {Timestamp('2016-01-10 00:00:00', freq='15T'): 0.0,
 Timestamp('2016-01-10 00:15:00', freq='15T'): 0.0,
 Timestamp('2016-01-10 00:30:00', freq='15T'): 0.0,
 Timestamp('2016-01-10 00:45:00', freq='15T'): 0.0,
 Timestamp('2016-01-10 01:00:00', freq='15T'): 0.0}'

Comment: I have also add the output of tail, it looks like this : {Timestamp('2016-12-10 22:00:00', freq='15T'): 0.0,
 Timestamp('2016-12-10 22:15:00', freq='15T'): 0.0,
 Timestamp('2016-12-10 22:30:00', freq='15T'): 0.0,
 Timestamp('2016-12-10 22:45:00', freq='15T'): 0.0,
 Timestamp('2016-12-10 23:00:00', freq='15T'): 0.0}

Comment: I have only data for Month of September (10), I am getting here for December as well.

Comment: Actually, might be your value column that is the problem.  When I print out, looks like this:  `0.0 0.5` but you have `0 0.5`.  I think for floats you should see same number of decimals displayed throughout column.  I bet dtype is object for the value column, but you want it to be float or int (float in this case as you have decimals).  Try `to_numeric` on the value column

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure your dates are strings

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df.value.resample('15T').sum()
```

Comment: @ayhan not sure. I'll test it out

Comment: I even tried this 

     df.index=pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Date']). This is also giving me the same result. I have data only for September, but after I re-sample I am getting data for other months as well.